# how to call a particular URL in Jenkins stage pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 different Jenkins pipeline (Say Pipeline1 and Pipeline2) in 2 different Jenkins hosts - Say Host - Jenkins1 and Jenkins2.

Jenkins1 with Pipeline1 has different stages for Deployment in an environment.
Jenkins2 with Pipeline2 has the stages for smoke testing for the same environment for different types.

I have taken the urls from Jenkins2 with Pipeline2 and have them ready as below:
These are the urls to be triggered after the deployment in Jenkins1 - Pipeline1.

https://test-jenkins2.com/job/TestRepo/buildWithParameters?token=test&testType=4
https://test-jenkins2.com/job/TestRepo/buildWithParameters?token=test&testType=5
https://test-jenkins2.com/job/TestRepo/buildWithParameters?token=test&testType=6
https://test-jenkins2.com/job/TestRepo/buildWithParameters?token=test&testType=7

So how do I trigger these urls in a stage step in Jenkins1 and Pipeline1 with my credentials?

```
stages {
        stage('Trigger Testing URLs') {
            agent { label '' }
            steps {
                ??????HOW To Trigger the above Jenkins URL in this stage???????
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `curl` to achieve this. Since you already have the URL to call:

```
curl -X POST -u username:password -g https://test-jenkins2.com/job/TestRepo/buildWithParameters?token=test&testType=4
```

Curl is available for both Windows and Linux systems so this should be applicable either way.

```
stage('Trigger Testing URLs') {
    agent { label '' }
    steps {
        curl -X POST -u username:password -g https://test-jenkins2.com/job/TestRepo/buildWithParameters?token=test&testType=4
        curl -X POST -u username:password -g https://test-jenkins2.com/job/TestRepo/buildWithParameters?token=test&testType=5
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer !!
Inside the Steps, how should I use it ?

 sh '''
curl -X POST -u username:password -g https://test-jenkins2.com/job/TestRepo/buildWithParameters?token=test&testType=4
        curl -X POST -u username:password -g https://test-jenkins2.com/job/TestRepo/buildWithParameters?token=test&testType=5
'''

or just the curl commands inside the steps without any sh ?

Comment: You should use `sh` since you would be running it within bash